# NativeScript WebView Android video plays sound but no image

Tags: android, webview, nativescript

Trying to play video in a WebView on Android. The video should play autoplay and inline with sound. But now image is shown.

Code from my NativeScript project:

```
if (platform.isAndroid) {
    webView.android.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);//android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT);//
    webView.android.setLayerType(android.view.View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);


} else if (platform.isIOS) {
    webView.ios.scrollView.bounces = false;
    webView.ios.scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false;
    webView.ios.scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false;
    webView.ios.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor;
    webView.ios.opaque = false;

    // Stop zooming
    webView.ios.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0;
    webView.ios.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 1.0;
    webView.ios.scalesPageToFit = false;
    webView.ios.scrollView.bounces = false;
}
```

As you can see I have done server settings for the iOS and it works great. Now I like to do the same for Android.

Please help!

best regards,
/Erik

Answer (score 0):

It did work if I change the line:

```
webView.android.setLayerType(android.view.View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

to:

```
webView.android.setLayerType(android.view.View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
```